# Producing effects plots within the GLMMadaptive package

Tags: r

I am getting an inscrutable error message while trying to run effects plots on objects created using the `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model()`  and `effects::predictorEffect()` functions.

Here is an example problem created from toy binary longitudinal data, created using code supplied with one of the vignettes included with the `GLMMadaptive` package.

```
# Library Relevant Packages
library(GLMMadaptive)
library(effects)

# Now we constuct a data frame with the design: 
# everyone has a baseline measurment, and then measurements at random follow-up times
DF <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_len(n), each = K),
                 time = c(replicate(n, c(0, sort(runif(K - 1, 0, t_max))))),
                 sex = rep(gl(2, n/2, labels = c("male", "female")), each = K))

# design matrices for the fixed and random effects
X <- model.matrix(~ sex * time, data = DF)
Z <- model.matrix(~ time, data = DF)

betas <- c(-2.13, -0.25, 0.24, -0.05) # fixed effects coefficients
D11 <- 0.48 # variance of random intercepts
D22 <- 0.1 # variance of random slopes

# we simulate random effects
b <- cbind(rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D11)), rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D22)))
# linear predictor
eta_y <- as.vector(X %*% betas + rowSums(Z * b[DF$id, ]))
# we simulate binary longitudinal data
DF$y <- rbinom(n * K, 1, plogis(eta_y))
```

Now when we fit a longitudinal logistic regression using the mixed_model function...

```
# fit the mixed effects logistic regression for y assuming random intercepts and random slopes for the random-effects part.
fm <- mixed_model(fixed = y ~ sex * time, 
                  random = ~ time | id, 
                  data = DF,
                  family = binomial())
```

...and try to create an effects plot using the `effects::predictorEffect()` function...

```
plot(predictorEffect("time", fm), type = "link")
```

...we get the following error

```
Error in mod.matrix %*% scoef : non-conformable arguments
```

**Has anyone encountered this problem before and if so, found a way to solve it?**

Comment: @Dimitris Rizopoulos, just thought I'd make you aware of this. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: This likely just means that `effects` does not support these models. Any reason you aren't using the `effectPlotData` provided witj `GLMMadaptive` itself?

Comment: the `effectPlotData()` function does work @ Axeman, I was just going through the vignette and wondered why the `predictorEffect()` function wasn't working. It's unusual for code supplied in a vignette not to work. Not unheard of, but unusual.

Comment: Ah ok, it wasn't clear to me that the `predictorEffect` code was also from the vignette. You should open an issue on github.